# c++ clr with ZeroC Ice 3.5.1

Tags: c++-cli, ice

I have a need to compile an existing message library generated using ZeroC's ICE with c++ clr.

I've been at this for a while and I'm having no luck.

I have a very simple .ice message file defined.
Upon generating the cpp and h files for this, I try to compile them into a .dll.
My slice2cpp command line args are

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\ZeroC\Ice-3.5.1\bin\slice2cpp.exe --depend --dll-export=ENABLE_DLL -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\ZeroC\Ice-3.5.1\slice" -I".\.." --underscore  "E:\test\platform\platform\testMessage.ice"
```

This generates me a testMessage.cpp and testMessage.h files.
Upon attempting to compile these, I get the error:

```
Error   7   error LNK2028: unresolved token (0A00098D) "class IceUtil::Shared * __cdecl IceInternal::upCast(class IceInternal::ObjectFactoryManager *)" (?upCast@IceInternal@@$$FYAPEAVShared@IceUtil@@PEAVObjectFactoryManager@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl IceInternal::Handle<class IceInternal::ObjectFactoryManager>::Handle<class IceInternal::ObjectFactoryManager>(class IceInternal::Handle<class IceInternal::ObjectFactoryManager> const &)" (??0?$Handle@VObjectFactoryManager@IceInternal@@@IceInternal@@$$FQEAA@AEBV01@@Z)   E:\test\platform\platform\testMessage.obj   platform
```

As per usual with Ice, I have to link the Iced.lib and IceUtild.lib files.
I compile with no pre compiled headers and /clr option on (not pure clr or safe) 
using VS2013. The body of the testMessage.ice file is very simple.

```
#ifndef _MESSAGE_ICE_
#define _MESSAGE_ICE_

module messaging {

class Message
{
    string clientId;
    string origin;
    string destination;
    string messageType;
    string suffix;
};

sequence<Message> MessageSeq;

class NonQueuedMsg extends messaging::Message {};

};

#endif
```

Compiling without the CLR option on results in success.

I imagine this is all caused by my lack of familiarity with c++ clr.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The language is called *C++/CLI*. CLR is the runtime environment.

Comment: Ok. The compiler option is /clr right?

Comment: Oh my, template linking errors.  You gotta look on the bright side.  By the time you figured this out, you'll never ever get the name wrong again.  Character-building stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem after the migration of my projects to vs 2013.

The project c++ with ice compile fine
but the project c++/cli with ice don't links.

I fixed linking problem in ObjectFactoryManagerF.h :

```
#ifdef __cplusplus_cli
IceUtil::Shared* upCast(ObjectFactoryManager* p) { return (IceUtil::Shared*) p; };
#else
IceUtil::Shared* upCast(ObjectFactoryManager* );
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I stopped trying to make C++/CLI and ICE-generated code work together after I read on their forum [here](https://www.zeroc.com/forums/help-center/6384-ice-3-5-1-c-cli.html) that they didn't support it.
What I've done.. I've made native static library on the client's side where I had C++/CLI. Static library fully encapsulated all communication stuff and was referenced from C++/CLI part. As a result I've got a *Mixed (C++/CLR) Recommended Rules* assembly. It works fine plus I've got easier portable application.